# Помогите решить проблему mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. У меня есть таблица serial, season, episode. Мне нужно выполнить эти два запроса, чтобы вывести для сериала какая последняя серия добавлена и из какого она сезона.
Первый запрос выполняется правильно, а второй дает warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in. Я начинающий. Если не сложно объясните пожалуйста что я делаю в этих запросах не так.

```
$querySeason = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM season WHERE serial_id =".$serial["id"]." ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1");
$season = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querySeason);
$queryEpisode = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM episode WHERE serial_id =".$serial["id"]." AND season_id=".$season["id"]." ORDER BY id DESC");
$episode = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEpisode);
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Для начала объясните, что это за переменные `$resultSeasons` и `$resultEpisodes `?

Comment: Прошу прощения код querySeason это и есть ResultSeason просто я сейчас копался пытался изменить и поэтому не заметил, код рабочий проблема только в warning. Спасибо. Я уже поправил.

Comment: У меня вся проблема заключается в том, что первый запрос выполняется без ошибок, второй дает warning, но также работает. Warning $episode = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryEpisode); дает вот эта строчка.